# My Hyper-V vm doesn't have internet connectivity after installing NordVPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Like the title says, after I installed nordvpn my VMs don't connect to the internet. I tried disabling NordVPN completely and restarting my machine but the problem still persists. My VM is connected to the Default Switch and I have enabled forwarding on the windows firewall for that particular switch. The VM used to connect to the Internet before but it does not do that anymore, I uninstalled NordVPN and it fixed the issue. I am also unable to see my vEthernet default switch and the WSL switch in the network and sharing center.

How do I make sure that my vSwitches tunnel traffic through the NordVPN TAP and how do I configure the settings of these vSwitches if they don't appear in the networking center?

Comment: Please provide your routing table using `route print`

Answer (score -1):

When setting up a VPN it means that all traffic is going through the VPN. To be able to access the internet you probably need something like split tunneling.

[https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/19618692366865-What-is-Split-Tunneling-and-how-to-use-it#:~:text=On%20Android%3A,choose%20the%20Split%20tunneling%20option](https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/19618692366865-What-is-Split-Tunneling-and-how-to-use-it#:%7E:text=On%20Android%3A,choose%20the%20Split%20tunneling%20option)

---

You can manage your hyper-v switches using PowerShell

```
Get-VMSwitch
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Or the Hyper-V MMC

To be able to access the internet you probably need to create some static routes and change your routing table to influence the traffic.